# Getting lease error while deploying ovf template in vmware

Tags: vmware

Lease state changes from initializing to error after few seconds while deploying ovf template in vCenter.

Please help me out on this issue any suggestions would be great for me thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of VMWare are you using? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i am using VMWare 5.5 version. using while loop i am waiting upto that lease state as ready, but that's also not working for me and one more thing i wrote function like wait for task using this function also i didn't see any progress in my code. If you know anything please help me out on this. Sorry for my poor English

Comment: when i am running the deploy script first time it shows as "initializing" and then immediately it shows error as "The operation is not supported on the object"  in V center task bar. Is there any solution to resolve this error/any suggesitions?